# Can Amazon Lightsail run containers built for arm platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, cloud, amazon-lightsail

I'm currently running a web server on Lightsail containers which are built on the x86 platform. Will Lightsail be able to run containers that are built on arm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Lightsail only supports the amd64 architecture. If you try to run an image built with arm64 or another architecture, you will receive an 'exec user process caused "exec format error"' in your Lightsail deployment logs.